# Multi-platform application launcher

Tags: java, native, launcher, multiplatform

Is there any application that creates an native application launcher of Java application? As the "native" term I mean "looks like normal, platform-dependent application, that only launches the java -jar foobar.jar, and displays the error if there're no JVM installed". I heard about Launch4j, but it only works for Windows. I want multi-platform (Win+Lin+Mac) solution. And I'm not talking about shell scripts; I want normal executable file.

Btw., Eclipse looks that it has got something like that I want.

Regards.

Comment: For an application that is over 200MB? :P And .jnlp doesn't look like native application.

Comment: *"For an application that is over 200MB"* Well it is only downloaded once - whatever launcher you use, it will have to be downloaded too. *"jnlp doesn't look like native application"* The launch process does not.

Comment: @m4tx  How will the app. be delivered to the end user?  CD/DVD, USB drive, Wi-Fi, [IPoAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers)?

Comment: @AndrewThompson +1 I did not know IPoAC - Will definitely give it a try for my next project!!!

Comment: @assylias I don't want to let the user need to have internet connection when (s)he launches my application. I recently didn't have an (temporairly) internet connection when launching SwingX demo (which is .jnlp); I couldn't start it altough I downloaded it before. It's really annoying.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - currently I aim on HTTP. It isn't over 200MB at the moment, but I'm pretty sure it will be :) And like I said - I don't want to give ability to launch application when user doesn't have internet connection at the moment.

Comment: *"I couldn't start it altough I downloaded it before."*  They must not specify the `offline-allowed` flag.  Add that and the app. can be used off-line (so long as the internet connection is there to install it in the first place).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using maven, then it would be very easy to create Native application for all platform, we use launch4j for windows(.exe), for debian(.deb) we use jdeb and for Mac OSX(.app and .dmg) we use osxappbundle.

Comment: Oh, cool, but... What about universal (not-only-debian) Linux launcher? :)

Comment: for non debian.... you can use [rpm-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/) to create rpm packages...

Comment: Hmmm... RPMs are still not universal launchers ;p As "universal" I mean plain ELF launchers. But Maven looks really good for me...

Comment: You can use Redline RPM Library with Ant or Maven to create RPMs. Look at LibGDX Packr too (for native launchers).

Answer (score 2):

There are tools like [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) that do this.

You can use it together with [izPack](http://izpack.org/) in order to provide a native installer and launcher. See [this](http://izpack.org/documentation/izpack-utils.html) for extra details.

Comment: I said that I don't want launch4j, because it works only on Windows :)

Comment: @m4tx You said `Java4j`. Launch4j works on linux and MacOS as well.

Comment: "Launch4j wraps jars in Windows native executables and allows to run them like a regular Windows program. It's possible to wrap applications on Windows, Linux, Mac OS X and Solaris! "

Comment: @Dan as far as I know, "It's possible to wrap applications on Windows, Linux, Mac OS X and Solaris!" means that I can only **create** launchers for **Windows** on Windows, Linux, OS X or Solaris :)

Comment: @Baz, sorry. I mean Launch4j, not Java4j. I fixed it already.

Comment: @Dan izPack? I'm watching its project page and it seems it provides installers for the Java software and Windows-only launchers. Btw., why every Java app launcher creator creates launchers only for Windows? I didn't see any app like that, which creates launchers for Linux...

Comment: I think Windows is the main target platform.

Comment: The main platforms are Windows and Linux. Then Mac.

Answer (score 2):

I use [LibGDX Packr](https://github.com/libgdx/packr) but it uses the JVM that you package with your application instead of the JVM installed on the operating system. As I prefer providing real GNU Linux packages, I use [JDeb](https://github.com/tcurdt/jdeb) and [Redline RPM](http://redline-rpm.org). I will have to find a solution to create a MSI package for Windows.

Those tools are cross-platform, it means that you don't have to be under Mac OS X to create an .app file, you don't have to be under Windows to create a zipped file with a native Windows launcher, you don't have to be under GNU Linux to create GNU Linux packages.

I use Ant as a build tool but you can do the same with Maven, both [JDeb](https://github.com/tcurdt/jdeb) and [Redline RPM](http://redline-rpm.org) support it, writing an Ant task for [LibGDX Packr](https://github.com/libgdx/packr) is quite easy. I still hesitate to put my high level deployment tools into a separate library when I succeed in using [JDeb](https://github.com/tcurdt/jdeb) and [Redline RPM](http://redline-rpm.org) correctly. I'd like to use an homogeneous syntax in order to allow a developer to use the same parameters to create all native packages. Moreover, my code creates the .icns files for you, it is very helpful when you don't want to depend on native Mac OS X tools or any external applications, it's based on my patch of Apache Commons Imaging.

P.S: I put my own tool (JNDT) into a separate Ant script a few months ago, its documentation is [here](https://gouessej.wordpress.com/2014/11/22/ardor3d-est-mort-vive-jogamps-ardor3d-continuation-ardor3d-is-dead-long-life-to-jogamps-ardor3d-continuation/#jndt).

Answer (score 0):

I found [install4j](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html) useful for multi-platform application binding. It's easy to use and has nice graphical interface.

It supports **Windows + Linux + MacOSX + Unix**.
It can also bind JRE so that you can run it even if user did not have any JRE installed.

Comment: It has a poor support of Linux and Unix, numerous packaging options don't work at all (multi-architecture, release, ...), it has numerous limitations, it's not free of charge and it offers not a lot much than competing solutions. Moreover, numerous tools allow to bundle a JRE, not only install4j.